# How do i get only number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like

```
11.7 km
```

and I need get only int( 11.7 ), how can I do this with JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple googling would solve your problem. Why waste a question on this?

Comment: Try [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: parseInt will return 11 instead of 11.7 :p

Comment: Do you want an int (ie. `11`) or a float (ie.`11.7`)?

Comment: What about parseFloat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
var numbers = distance.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
alert(numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks it is working good. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the parseInt().
Example:

```
var string = "11.7 km";
alert(parseInt(string));
```

This would alert: "11".

In your case you have a float, so you could use:

```
alert(parseFloat(string));
```

This gives an alert with "11.7".

[ParseFloat reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

[ParseInt reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` method by passing a `regex` *expression* as argument.

```js
console.log('11.7 km'.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFloat('11.7km')` this will return `11.7`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```js
console.log(Number(("11.7 km").replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you can use is a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), using the **match** function:

```
your_text = "11.7 km";
r = new RegExp("\\d|\\.","g");
matched_number = your_text.match(r);
number = matched_number.join("");
number_float = parseFloat(number)
```

Comment: This will give `117` as result, not really what is wanted!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to match for the "dot" character. This code is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will match all numerical values in a string, regardless of text before or after the value.

```js
var str = "11.7 km\n" +
  "Text before 11.7 km\n" +
  "11.7 km Text after\n" +
  "Text before 11.7 km Text after\n";
  
var matches = str.match(/(\.\d*)*\d+(\.\d*)*/igm).map(parseFloat);

console.log('string "' + str + '" has ' + matches.length + " matches:");

console.log(matches);
```